# stop adb from discovering network debug android devices

Tags: android, adb

I have some strange problem. I use only usb connection to debug my android device. But whenever an android device that enables network debugging is also connected to my network, suddenly I see it in `adb devices`.
How can I stop adb from watching my network?

Disconnecting the device with `adb disconnect` works partially since at some point my workstation reconnects to it.

Other users on the same network don't see the same, so I guess it's a matter of configuration/version. My version:

```
>adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.0-6374843
Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb
```

I use MacOS if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

`pf` / [`pfctl`](https://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/) should be able to block the device by it's IP address.

Comment: I sometimes get other devices that connect to my network